# Apache Spark 2.2 JobProgressListener alternative

Tags: scala, apache-spark

JobProgressListener is deprecated since Apache Spark 2.2.0. Which one should I use instead of that?

Answer (score 0):

Create your own `SparkListener` instead. Add a class extending `SparkListener` and override the methods you want to use to track the Spark Job progress. Example:

```
class CustomSparkListener extends SparkListener {
 override def onApplicationStart(ev: SparkListenerApplicationStart): Unit = ???

 override def onStageSubmitted(stageSubmitted: SparkListenerStageSubmitted): Unit = ???
}
```

You also have to declare your new Spark Listener in the SparkSession configuration:

```
.config("spark.extraListeners", "listeners.CustomSparkListener")
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: I don't want to create own SparkListener. I just want to access JobProgressListener, but while accessing it I read @deprecated annotation. So your answer is correct if I wanted to create own SparkListener and then register it but unhelpful otherwise.

Comment: I beg to differ I think it was quite helpful